# portable executables with gfortran?

Tags: windows, fortran, gfortran, mingw-w64

I'm using gfortran with minGW under windows to generate 64-bit executables. It works great.  What I'd like to do, however, it to provide executable to other folk who do not have minGW on their machine.  I.e. to make fully portable code.  (Some of the folk who use the programs have "locked" machines, where the system administrators would not allow them to install minGW.)  Any suggestion on how I can make the executables such that they can be used on any machine that can run 64-bit windows, without that anything else has to be installed on the machine running the executable?

Comment: Which errors do you have? It can create portable executables, you just need to ditribute the runtime libraries with your program.

Comment: -static is the usual link flag to make you executable program "portable" (all libraries are embedded in the executable)

Comment: Simple answer that works!  Thank you very much!  Had looked in the manual under options, searching for the term "portable" but not spotted it.  Of course with "-static" I can find it.  This is what the manual says:



Quote

-static-libgfortran
On systems that provide ‘libgfortran’ as a shared and a static library, this
option forces the use of the static version. If no shared version of ‘libgfortran’ was built when the compiler was configured, this option has no effect.
2.8 Influencing

unquote

From that it was not that clear to me!